# difficulty with bootstrap container - django-bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I fix this problem without removing the `bootstrap  template tags`?

Context:

I have the following template schema:

`layout.html` is my base template

And I have another templates which inherit from `layout.html`

I am using third party package application django-bootstrap3

My `layout.html` is:

**(The divs amount of navbar and django variables templates does not matter - are just for demonstration)**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
<html lang="es">
{% block head %}
<head>
    <title>{% block title_tag %}My APP{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</head>
{% endblock %}
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Nav menu -->
    <header>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            {% if userprofile %}
                <div class="profile-options">
                    {% comment %} Begin settings drowdown {% endcomment %}
                    <div class="name-options-cont">
                        <div class="name">
                            <p>{{ userprofile.user.email }} - {{ userprofile.user.enterprise_name }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="options">
                            <div class="drop-down">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="{% url 'some-url'  %}" >Some option</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{% url 'some-url2'  %}" >Some option2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Exit</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                <div class="registration">
                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Registrarse</a><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Iniciar sesión</a>
                </div>
        {% endif %}
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            <div class='alert {% if "success" in message.tags %}alert-success{% elif "warning" in message.tags%}alert-
            warning{% elif "error" in message.tags %}alert-danger{% endif %} alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
                <!-- Boton para cerrar el alert-->
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <!--End Boton para cerrar el alert
                     Haciendo uso del Django messages framework-->
                    {% if "safe" in message.tags %}{{ message|safe }}{%else%}{{ message }}{% endif %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% block body_content %}
    {% endblock body_content %}
</div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My `article_detail.html` template inherits from `layout.html`.

In this template I am retrieving an object information in Django, and rendering the specific information of an article post.

In the `layout.html` **the divs amount and django variables templates does not matter - are just for demonstration**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_content %}

<!-- Right column -->
<div class="search-column">
    <div class="post-column">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="{% static 'img/icons/info.svg' %}" alt="">
                <span>Información</span>
            </div>
            <div class="autor">
                <p class="title">Autor</p>
                <div class="profile">
                    <div class="img-cont">
                        <a href="#">
                            {% if instance.author.avatar%}
                        <img src="{{ instance.author.avatar.url }}" alt="">
                            {% else %}
                               <img src="{% static 'img/default_profile_pic.png' %}" class="img-responsive">
                            {% endif %}

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-review-cont">

                        {% comment %} A quien corresponda {% endcomment %}
                        <a href="#">
                            {% if instance.author.get_long_name %}
                            <span>{{ instance.author.get_long_name }}</span>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if instance.author.get_enterprise_name %}
                            <span>{{ instance.author.get_enterprise_name }} (@{{ instance.author.email }})</span>
                            {% endif %}
                        </a>
                        <p><div class="fb-like" data-href="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }" data-layout="standard"
                                data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
                        </p>
                        <hr/>
                        {% comment %}
                        <img src="{% static 'img/stars.svg' %}" alt="">
                        <div class="average">
                            <span>546</span>
                            <span>valoraciones</span>
                        </div>
                        {% endcomment %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End right column-->

<!-- Main content -->
<main>
    <div class="blog-body">
        {% if instance.image %}
        <img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
        {% endif %}

        <div class="title-cont">
            <h1>{{ title }} <small>{% if instance.draft %}<span style='color: red'> Borrador</span> {% endif %}{{ instance.publish }}</small> </h1>
            {% comment %}
            {% if instance.author.has_perm %}
                {{ instance.author.has_perm }}
            {% endif %}
            {% endcomment %}
            {% comment %} <h1>{{ title }} <small>{{ instance.timestamp|timesince }}</small> </h1>{% endcomment %}
        </div>
        <div class="main-text">
            {{ instance.content|linebreaks }}<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<!-- End main content -->
{% endblock %}
```

When I go to the article detail view via browser, I found at design level of following:

[image]

I have been checking in `Inspect elements` and I think (I don't know if I am in right) that there is a `<div class="container"> .. </div>` element which override this visual space in blank:

[image]

I think this in relation that if will does not this `<div class="container"> .. </div>` element my blue section code, would be located properly and not so far down the page.

This `<div class="container"> .. </div>` element is brought by django-bootstrap3 which I am using, such as follow in the following picture:

[image]

If I go to my `layout.html` template mentioned previously above, and I remove the following template tags bootstrap related:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
```

and refresh my `article_detail.html` in the browser, the visual space blank is fixed